Routing and Remote Access will not start on Windows Server 2022
I'm trying to setup an L2TP/IPSec VPN on Windows Server 2022.
Within "Add Roles and Features" in Server Manager
Go to "Routing and Remote Access" and select "Configure and Enable Routing and Remote Access" but it fails when starting the service. If I try to start the service multiple times I get the same result.
When take a look on Event Viewer I see the message
The Routing and Remote Access service terminated with the following service-specific error: 
A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.

Does anyone have any advice for this error ?

You could try to install it using Powershell.i suspect it's not configured, if I'm correct that can only be done using Powershell, here is an example
# Install Remote Access Role
Install-WindowsFeature RemoteAccess -IncludeManagementTools

# Configure Remote Access
Install-RemoteAccess -VpnType Vpn

# Configure VPN
Add-VpnS2SInterface -Name "VPN Interface" -ServerAddress <Server_Address> -AuthenticationMethod MSChapv2 -TunnelType L2tp -EncryptionLevel Required -L2tpPsk <Pre_Shared_Key>

# Allow inbound VPN connections
Set-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Routing and Remote Access (PPTP-In)" -Enabled True
Set-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Routing and Remote Access (L2TP-In)" -Enabled True

# Enable VPN Access
Grant-RemoteAccess -EnableVpnType Vpn -Force

